# Pacemaker Corosync VIP switches when node is brought online

Tags: high-availability, pacemaker, corosync

I've a cluster setup with 3 nodes [having nodes A,B (VIP),C] using pacemaker and corosync. When I shutdown one of the nodes `B` intentionally (as a disaster recovery test), the node `A` or `C` takes VIP but when I turn back B on after  sometime then VIP switches to `B` which should not be the case.

I would expect `A` or `C` to retain VIP, below is my pacemaker config

```
configure
primitive baseos-ping-check ocf:pacemaker:ping params host_list="1.2.3.4" multiplier="1000" dampen="0" attempts="2" \
        op start interval="0s" timeout="60s" \
        op monitor interval="2s" timeout="60s" \
        op stop interval="0s" timeout="60s" on-fail="ignore"
primitive baseos-vip-master ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 \
        params ip="192.67.23.145" iflabel="MR" cidr_netmask="255.255.255.0" \
        op start interval="0s" \
        op monitor interval="10s" \
        op stop interval="0s"
clone cl_baseos-ping-check baseos-ping-check meta interleave="true"
location loc-vip-master vip-master \
        rule $id="loc-vip-master-rule" $role="master" 100: #uname eq ECS01 \
        rule $id="loc--vip-master-rule-0" $role="master" -inf: not_defined pingd or pingd lte 0
property expected-quorum-votes="1"
property stonith-enabled="false"
property maintenance-mode="false"
property cluster-recheck-interval="5min"
property default-action-timeout="60s"
property pe-error-series-max="500"
property pe-input-series-max="500"
property pe-warn-series-max="500"
property no-quorum-policy="ignore"
property dc-version="1.1.16-94ff4df"
property cluster-infrastructure="corosync"
rsc_defaults resource-stickiness="150"
rsc_defaults migration-threshold="3"
commit
quit
```

My corosync config looks like:

```
totem {
    version: 2

    cluster_name: debian


    token: 3000


    token_retransmits_before_loss_const: 10


    clear_node_high_bit: yes

    crypto_cipher: none
    crypto_hash: none

    interface {

        ringnumber: 0
        bindnetaddr: 127.0.0.1
        mcastport: 5405
        ttl: 1
    }
}

logging {
    fileline: off
    to_stderr: no
    to_logfile: no
    to_syslog: yes
    syslog_facility: daemon
    debug: off
    timestamp: on
    logger_subsys {
        subsys: QUORUM
        debug: off
    }
}

quorum {
    provider: corosync_votequorum
    expected_votes: 2
}
```

Can someone please suggest where I'm mistaking.